# color the lines of logcat on Linux [android]

Tags: android, linux, colors, terminal, logcat

The Logcat in Eclipse has colors for errors, warning, debug, ...
How can I do to get the same result on Linux (Ubuntu) when I run the command 'adb -e logcat' in a terminal to get it colored?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Link with script](https://web.archive.org/web/20200401114949/http://jsharkey.org/logcat/)

I think it will be useful for you and you can change script by yourself;)

Comment: before that change execution permision.
1. In console type "chmod +x coloredlogcat.pytxt"
2. Or right button click and tab "permissions" and then click "allow execute file as program"

Now U can use it)

Comment: actually the issue was that I was trying to execute the python script just like it's written on Jeff's page, but I needed to add "python" before the command to execute it.

Comment: I recommend **checking out various forks of the script** which are hosted on github.com or gist.github.com; just search for "coloredlogcat". Projects such as [ColoredLogcatPlusPlus](https://github.com/gjtorikian/ColoredLogcatPlusPlus) did several improvements. The original script was prepared for Windows afaik.

Comment: http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/     Doesn't work when PIPED. Works only when run as a script. any help?

Comment: @AKh can you please provide more details. What OS, what python versions and the command you have used.

Answer (score 37):

`adb logcat -v color`

from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#formatmodify)

Answer (score 10):

This is my view of "colorizing" the logcat:
https://bitbucket.org/brunobraga/logcat-colorize

[image]

Comment: I find this tool incredibly useful. I added a few fixes and I also shared a snap package: https://snapcraft.io/logcat-colorize.

Answer (score 3):

My favourite is [pidcat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat), maintained by Jake Wharton based off of Jeff Sharkey's script (mentioned by Yaroslav Boichuk).

I have also used [logcat-color](https://github.com/marshall/logcat-color), maintained by Marshall Culpepper, (also based off of Jeff's script) which allows you to create profiles you can activate (log per task, or per application, etc).

I have preferred pidcat because at the time logcat-color wouldn't filter by package name, and I never went back to try again once it was [added](https://github.com/marshall/logcat-color/issues/9). Seems to be reasonably popular still as well.

Answer (score 2):

And yet another script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :; do 
    adb $@ logcat | sed \
    -e 's:^V/:\x00\x1b[0;35m:g'  \
    -e 's:^D/:\x00\x1b[0;36m:g'  \
    -e 's:^I/:\x00\x1b[0;32m:g'  \
    -e 's:^W/:\x00\x1b[0;33m:g'  \
    -e 's:^E/:\x00\x1b[0;31m:g'  \
    -e 's:^F/:\x00\x1b[0;31m:g'  \
    -e '/Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags/d' \
    -e '/The application may be/d'
   sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python, **PyLogAnalyser** can filter, colorize and analyse all type of logs in Linux, Windows and Mac (and Cygwin).

You can install it directly from PyPI:

```
python -m pip install pyloganalyser
```

And call it in order to print the log for the standard output (also, for text or HTML output):

```
adb logcat -v threadtime | python -m loganalyser --stdin --stdout -c Android_logcat_threadtime.conf
```

The file 'Android_logcat_threadtime.conf' is included in the module directory. So the actual invocation could be:

```
CONFPATH="$(python -c 'import loganalyser;print loganalyser.__file__.replace("/__init__.pyc","")')";
adb logcat -v threadtime | python -m loganalyser --stdin --stdout -c "$CONFPATH"/android/Android_logcat_threadtime.conf
```

[Website: http://pyloganalyser.sourceforge.net](http://pyloganalyser.sourceforge.net)

Comment: pip3 install pyloganalyser & export CONFPATH="$(python3 -c 'import loganalyser;print(loganalyser.__file__.replace("/__init__.py",""))')" & loganalyser ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with [lnav](http://lnav.org/) , add logcat config from [here](https://github.com/javierhz/lnav-logcat-Android)